# Are questions that do not specify a region considered too broad?

Tags: discussion, close-reasons, broad-questions

Laws are obviously different around the world. From country to province to territory to state, even from county to county. When asking questions about laws that can have different answers based on region, should you be required to specify your region and tag your country/province/state that your seeking an answer for?

Answer (score 1):

We certainly *should* consider them to be too broad. Broad-ness at least seems to me to be the biggest issue we're having right now, aside from the debate on legal advice. [There are](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/1/are-there-any-kinds-of-laws-that-prohibit-personally-harmful-speech) [quite a few](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/172/who-has-the-right-of-way-at-an-intersection-next-to-a-parking-lot-in-north-ameri) [questions](https://law.stackexchange.com/questions/166/how-to-handle-an-issue-not-covered-by-the-renters-agreement) that are completely unanswerable because they don't specify a jurisdiction.

There may be, of course, situations where a user doesn't know how specific they have to be (for example, many elements of United States law vary by state, and that's not always common knowledge) but at the very least we should require questions to ask about a specific country or countries, unless they're asking about international law.

Comment: could be interesting to have multiple valid answers based on location. Having one question with different answers based on location. But this may require a rework of how the site runs and that may not be in the cards.